# ZIP Format Repeating character

Tags: python, format, zip

This is a theoretical question. This could be accomplished in any language but I am using python at the moment. I want to make a zip archive that will to expand to a rather large amount of repeating data. Is it possible to create a zip file that will expand to a predictable number of characters? For instance, if I zip file that will expand to `foo.txt` and contain the data `aaaaaaaa`,  how difficult would it be to modify it so the resulting `foo.txt` will contain 10 letter a's, or more? Can this be accomplished in python without any external libraries?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the zip format has a builtin checksum that you would have to change as for the purpose of verify that the data is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look to the implementation of [zipstream](https://github.com/SpiderOak/ZipStream/blob/master/zipstream.py), specifically, [zip_file](https://github.com/SpiderOak/ZipStream/blob/master/zipstream.py#L244). I believe you a can quickly modify the code there to generate a file that's roughly what you're looking for.